# Is there way to export Cache/Table DDL in Ignite-GridGain community edition?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are using gridgain-community-8.8.10. Is there way to export all or selected Cache/Tables and import into another cluster?

I am primarily looking to export only the structure and data is optional

Source and target environment : 3 node Ignite-GridGain cluster running on VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be just to run same DDLs on seconds cluster, since AFAIK there is no facilities for dumping or porting existing SQL tables.

If all your tables and caches were defined via cache configurations (with query entities) You can try to write a small app which will iterate over all caches introspect their configuration and create similar in seconds cluster.

Also take a look to system views like `sys.columns`, `sys.tables`, `sys.caches`, they can be very helpful if original DDLs not available.